# Hsqldb version issue: Client driver version greater than . is required

Tags: hsqldb

I am getting following error in my hsqldb server.

[Server@85ede7b]: [Thread[HSQLDB Connection @17bf2dab,5,HSQLDB Connections @85ede7b]]: 0:Failed to connect client.  Stack trace follows.
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Client driver version greater than '-268.-50.-11.-82' is required.  HSQLDB server version is '2.3.2'
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.init(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to connect to a HSQLDB server but you are not using the HSQLDB version 2.3.2 jar on the client side. Check the jar is the same. Your connection url should also start with `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql:`.

The error also happens when you connect to HSQLDB server from software programs that are not related to HSQLDB, for example a web browser.

Comment: Hi, i am same version at both the places, and jdbc:hsqldb:file:test/test is my hsql connector

Comment: Your connection URL is not correct for server connections. The default localhost URL is `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/`

Comment: I got the error when opened it in the browser, so whats the correct way to  connect to HSQLDB server and what is the appropriate software

Comment: See http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_hsqldb_jar on how to connect to the server. You can also use any JDBC client such as SQuirrel or DBVisualizer.