# HsqlException: Client version

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

This question is related to the same error message as in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777516/hsqldb-version-issue-client-driver-version-greater-than-is-required). However I couln'd solve my problem using the answers given there.

Im locally starting the HSQL Server using.

```
java-cp lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:MasterListMain --bname.0 MasterListMain
```

When I connect to the server I get:

```
[Server@4517d9a3]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@4517d9a3]: [Thread[main,5,main]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@4517d9a3]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
[Server@4517d9a3]: Could not load properties from file
[Server@4517d9a3]: Using cli/default properties only
[Server@4517d9a3]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@4517d9a3]: Server socket opened successfully in 0 ms.
[Server@4517d9a3]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:MasterListMain, alias=mastelistmain] opened successfully in 391 ms.
[Server@4517d9a3]: Startup sequence completed in 391 ms.
[Server@4517d9a3]: 2016-08-30 18:55:54.144 HSQLDB server 2.3.4 is online on por 9001
[Server@4517d9a3]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
[Server@4517d9a3]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Client driver version greater than '2.1.0.0' is requied.  HSQLDB server version is '2.3.4'
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Client driver version greater than '2.1.0.0' is requied.  HSQLDB server version is '2.3.4'
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is unexpected, since I was expecting that also my client uses version 2.3.4.

`gradle.build` reads as:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'


import groovy.sql.Sql

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


mainClassName = "gui.MasterListMain"

configurations {
    mail
    junit
    jdbc
    sqllite
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4+'
//    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.8.11.2'
      // hsqldb
    compile 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.4'
     // JAR
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'
     // Hibernate
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.10.Final'


    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.0.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.14'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.6.0'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.log4jdbc', name: 'log4jdbc', version: '1.2'
}
```

And also the `gradle dependencies` seem to be ok

```
default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- junit:junit:4+ -> 4.12
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.4
+--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.10.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|    +--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.10.Final
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|    |    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    |    |    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.5.Final
|    |    |    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA
|    |    |    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|    |    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA
|    |    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    |    \--- org.jboss:jandex:1.1.0.Final
|    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1 (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.5.Final (*)
|    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
+--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.0.2
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.0.2
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.0.2
+--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
+--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.14
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0
+--- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.0
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0
|    \--- log4j:log4j:1.2.14
\--- com.googlecode.log4jdbc:log4jdbc:1.2
     \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.0
```

In my client side log I find:

```
WARN    2016-08-30 19:24:02,314 501 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  [main]  HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
INFO    2016-08-30 19:24:02,314 501 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  [main]  HHH000401: using driver [org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver] at URL [jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/MasterListMain]
INFO    2016-08-30 19:24:02,314 501 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  [main]  HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=SA}
INFO    2016-08-30 19:24:02,314 501 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  [main]  HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
INFO    2016-08-30 19:24:02,314 501 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  [main]  HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
DEBUG   2016-08-30 19:24:02,314 501 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  [main]  Initializing Connection pool with 1 Connections
DEBUG   2016-08-30 19:24:03,439 1626    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider  [main]  Unable to build entity manager factory
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at 
    [...]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Any Idea, where to define the correct version?

Thanks, BerndGit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the root cause: hsql version was not updated automatically in eclipse after modifying gradle.build.

Question closed.