# Maven and Hsqldb: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Client driver version greater than '2.1.0.0' is required. HSQLDB server version is '2.3.4' (on mac)

Tags: java, database, eclipse, maven, hsqldb

**What I want to do**

- How to get maven/eclipse to point to 2.3.2 jar instead?
- Connect to the HSQL db via Java/jdbc (I assume I should be able to do this once I have solved the above)

**My settings**

It seems that my hsql server is using 2.3.4. However I do not see why my local Eclipse (the client) is using 2.1.0.0. I have set up maven and it seems to be pointing to the 2.3.2 jar.

[How my Eclipse package explorer looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnRUL.png)

**Other things I have checked / done**

- Updated my path variables in my bash_profile (*export HSQL_HOME=/Users/user/hsqldb; export PATH=$PATH:$HSQL_HOME/lib*)
- Have been able to create tables using GUI Database manager
- I have looked at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777516/hsqldb-version-issue-client-driver-version-greater-than-is-required) but it doesn't tell me how to resolve / check which jar version my client jar is using

**The solution**

As mentioned by fredt, upgrade to 2.3.4 by making the following change to my pom.xml. Also went to build path to make sure that there is no other hsqldb jars being pointed at (or if any where being pointed at, they were 2.3.4).

```
  <properties>
    <hsqldb.version>2.3.4</hsqldb.version>
  </properties>
```

Comment: post `pom.xml` code

Comment: Thanks Saravana, seems like the above was the pom.xml change required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is misleading. It is meant to say "greater than 2.3.3 is required". Change your Maven settings in pom.xml to require HSQLDB 2.3.4. In general you should use the same version jar for driver and server.