# RazorSQL causes HSQLDB to throw org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Client driver version greater than '2.1.0.0' is required. HSQLDB server version is '2.3.4'

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb, razorsql

I am not able to connect to my [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) database from [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/).  I am only having this issue when I am running in Server mode and when I am attempting to connect from [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/).

Using the same URL from Eclipse Data Source Explorer, and from the application itself (which is a Hibernate 5.2.7 application), I am able to successfully connect to my database at the URL "[jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/SudokuHibernate](http://jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/SudokuHibernate)".  Since I am running it in Server mode, I am able to connect concurrently.

(Note: I don't have to have multiple concurrent connections, but it make debugging easier). The database is being run in Server mode from the command line via ...

```
java -cp ../libs/hsqldb-2.3.4/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:/Users/arick/src/databases/SudokuHibernate --dbname.0 SudokuHibernate
```

When attempting to connect from [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/), the database console shows the error message.  *"org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Client driver version greater than '2.1.0.0' is required.  The [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) server version is '2.3.4'"*.

**Note**: This is a different question then [a similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586646/maven-and-hsqldb-org-hsqldb-hsqlexception-client-driver-version-greater-than), as all of my own configuration files are explicitly referencing the same JDBC driver, from the same jar file.  However, as pointed out by [Fred T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471070/fredt), the reference to '2.1.0.0', by [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), is somewhat misleading.  It is really just saying that the client and the server have two different versions of the JDBC driver.

At the same time that the database is throwing a mismatched version error, RazorSQL displays a dialog box with the error message:

```
ERROR: An error occurred while trying to make a connection to the database: 
JDBC URL: jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/SudokuHibernate
connection exception: connection failure: java.io.EOFException
```

Below is my [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) connection profile.

**RazorSQL Profile**
**Driver Location**: /Users/arick/src/libs/hsqldb-2.3.4/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar
**JDBC URL**: [jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/SudokuHibernate](http://jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/SudokuHibernate)

Comment: Contrary to you claims, RazorSQL is using a driver version 2.1 of HSQLDB (or at least not 2.3.4). So it is the same as the duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven and Hsqldb: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Client driver version greater than '2.1.0.0' is required. HSQLDB server version is '2.3.4' (on mac)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586646/maven-and-hsqldb-org-hsqldb-hsqlexception-client-driver-version-greater-than)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was inferred by [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466862/mark-rotteveel), the answer is similar to a related question about *[how to get Eclipse and Maven to talk to a HSQLDB server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586646/maven-and-hsqldb-org-hsqldb-hsqlexception-client-driver-version-greater-than)* that is running in standalone server mode.

In that case, *[Fred Toussi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471070/fredt)*, the lead on the [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) project, pointed out the answer was to modify the configuration file, that is used in Eclipse and Maven, to pull in the appropriate version of the [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) JDBC jar file, and also to make sure the jar file didn't appear anywhere else on the classpath.  Maven uses a `pom.xml` file for configuration; so what was needed was make sure that the correct version of the [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) was defined in the project's `pom.xml` file.

In my situation, the [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) product that I was using, just happens to use [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) as the embedded database for itself.  If I had been using any other Java database, I may not have had this problem.  But, since the [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) product had already loaded its own version of the [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) jar file, it didn't matter what I specified in my configuration for the database connection. It wasn't going to work.

No matter how I changed *my* driver profile, or *my* connection profile, the only version of the [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) jar file that was going to get loaded, was the original jar file, that was already in use by [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/), and that came with [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/).  (Note: This is true, *unless* [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) gets fancy, and it decides to use a different classloader, and some of the other tricks that are commonly used by Java applications servers to solve these problems).

As per suggestion from Dan Richardson, from [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/), the actual answer was *not* by modifying *my* configurations, but by changing the contents of the [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) distribution itself.  I needed to replace the `jar` file that is used by the [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) application.  This `jar` file is in Mac application folder for [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/).  This location is typically at `/Applications/RazorSQL.app/Contents/Java/drivers/hsqldb`.

(Note: If you are not familiar with how to open a Mac app folder, you just right-click on the [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/) folder name in the `/Applications` directory and use the *"Show Package Contents"* menu option). In my case, I renamed the original `hsqldb.jar` file to be `hsqldb_2.3.2.jar` file, and then I copied in the last distribution of the `hsqldb.jar`.